# Get all children of the current node

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
<div class='1'>
  <div class='2'>
    <div class='3'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

query('.1').children() // returns [<div class='2'></div>]
```

Is is possible to access 3rd level children by using query().children() instead of using something like `query('.1 .2 .3')?`

Basically, I would like to access all children of the current element without hard-coding its Id, e.g. `query('#foo .3')`

Comment: What about `query('#foo > * > *')`?

Comment: I don't have elements ID, that is the problem. I need to call smth like foo.query(); But I cannot find how to do it in Dojo. jQuery is more dome-oriented. But we stick with Dojo for more OOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- `element.querySelectorAll('div')` to get all `<div>` children of `element`
- `element.querySelectorAll('[class]')` to get all children of `element` that does have a `class` attribute
- `document.querySelectorAll('div[class]')` for the whole html document

You can use any CSS selector as a parameter for `querySelectorAll()`.